# Only Show First Record when click in datatable record

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

1. when I save the record in the table it works successfully.
2. when changing booking number and focus out it also works.
3. But when clicking on the ticket number, it only picks the first record and does not work for other records. solve the issue where it is

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#BookingNo").on("focusout", function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ticket-booking-status.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          BookingNo: $("#BookingNo").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#txtShowData").html(data);
        }
      });
    });

    $("#SaveTicketBooking").on("click", function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ticketbooking-insert.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          SaveTicketBooking: "SaveTicketBooking",
          BookingNo: $('#BookingNo').val(),
          TicketNo: $('#TicketNo').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#txtSaveTicketBooking").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="row">
  <form onsubmit="return false" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="BookingNo">Booking No</label>
      <input id="BookingNo" name="BookingNo" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $BookingNo; ?>" autofocus required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-sm-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="TicketNo">Ticket No</label>
      <input type="text" id="TicketNo" name="TicketNo" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="16" pattern=".{11,}" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="submit" id="SaveTicketBooking" name="SaveTicketBooking" value="Save Booking" class="btn btn-save btn-block">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="txtSaveTicketBooking"></div>
<div id="txtShowData"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#EditTicketBookingShow").on("click", function() {
      $.ajax({

        url: "ticket-booking-edit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          EditTicketBookingShow: "EditTicketBookingShow",
          SrNoShow: $("#SrNoShow").val(),
          TicketNoShow: $("#TicketNoShow").val(),
          BookingNoShow: $("#BookingNoShow").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#txtEditData").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<?php if (isset($_POST['BookingNo'])) { $BookingNo = $_POST['BookingNo']; } ?>

<?php
  $sql = "Select * from tblTicketBooking Where BookingNo = '$BookingNo' Order By SrNo";
  $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table id="viewreport" class="display" style="font-size:small">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Ticket</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        while($r=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
          $BookingNo = $r['BookingNo'];
          $TicketNo = $r['TicketNo']; ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <form onsubmit="return false" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="SrNoShow" name="SrNoShow" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $r['SrNo']; ?>">
                <input id="BookingNoShow" name="BookingNoShow" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $BookingNo; ?>">
                <input id="TicketNoShow" name="TicketNoShow" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $TicketNo; ?>">
                <input type="submit" id="EditTicketBookingShow" name="EditTicketBookingShow" value="EDIT" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
              </form>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $TicketNo; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#viewreport').removeClass('display').addClass('table table-bordered');
  </script>

    if (isset($_POST['EditTicketBookingShow'])) 
    {
      $BookingNo = $_POST['BookingNoShow']; 
      $SrNo = $_POST['SrNoShow']; 
      $TicketNo = $_POST['TicketNoShow']; 
      $getTicket = "Select * From tblTicketBooking Where TicketNo = '$TicketNo'"; $stmtTicket = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getTicket); 
      $rowTicket = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtTicket, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); ?>

      <script>
        document.getElementById("BookingNo").value = '<?php echo $rowTicket['
        BookingNo '] ?>';
        document.getElementById("TicketNo").value = '<?php echo $rowTicket['
        TicketNo '] ?>';
      </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please format your code to be readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Then edit your question - thanks

Comment: basically there are three php files code starting with first file named ticket.php and end at code <div id="txtShowData"></div> then start secod file with script named ticket-booking-status.php and end at script <script type="text/javascript">

  $('#viewreport')
    .removeClass( 'display' )
    .addClass('table table-bordered');
</script>  then start third file start with php code name ticket-booking-edit.php and end at <?php } ?>

Comment: Again please edit the question if you need to add more information - as you can see the that code is very hard to read in the comments. Thank you

Comment: And which is the button to "click on the ticket number", exactly? Is it the "txtShowData" element you just mentioned, or is it something else? Please be specific.

Comment: type a number in booking # box when focus out data show in datatable and there is button named edit. if there are multiple record of one booking # then only first edit button work

Comment: Ok. `$("#EditTicketBookingShow")` will only find the first edit button because it's using the ID to select it. An ID must be unique - otherwise by definition it's not an ID! If you have multiple buttons with the same ID, jQuery will ignore all except the first one because they are not valid HTML. Use classes instead to select and bind an event to multiple elements.

Comment: Hey Shahzad, welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to reduce the lines of code in your example to a specific section. This will help people better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make a simple edit page eg.
on edit page fetch values using GET method, and fetch / update like Where Booking No = "123"

table code

```
    <tbody>
          <?php
            while($r=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
              $BookingNo = $r['BookingNo'];
              $TicketNo = $r['TicketNo']; 
    
    echo '<tr>
    <td>1</td> <td>2nd text</td> <td><a href="edit-booking.php?'.$BookingNo.'">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>';
}
    ?>
```

Comment: I know this solution but i want to do it with post method without refresh page. have you any solution

Comment: see in this case, you can create a pop up e.g Boot strap modal, and use ajax, >>> whenever you will click on edit button, it has to fetch a value like entity booking no., you can do it using JS, upvote my answer and I will provide you link or techniq to do it